# matplotlib savefig error with bbox_inches='tight' and rasterize

Tags: matplotlib

When I run the rasterization example [found here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/misc/rasterization_demo.html) and add `bbox_inches='tight'` argument to any of the `savefig()` functions, I get the following error. Any one else have this issue? I couldnt find a bug report. Im using matplotlib 1.4.0 and python 2.7.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "raster.py", line 45, in <module>
    plt.savefig("test_rasterization.pdf", dpi=150,bbox_inches='tight')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 576, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1470, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2192, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2469, in print_pdf
    self.figure.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1079, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2092, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 58, in draw_wrapper
    before(artist, renderer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 43, in before
    renderer.start_rasterizing()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_mixed.py", line 96, in start_rasterizing
    self._bbox_inches_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/tight_bbox.py", line 86, in process_figure_for_rasterizing
    r = adjust_bbox(figure, bbox_inches, fixed_dpi)
NameError: global name 'figure' is not defined
```

Comment: It works fine for me, using python 2.7.8 and matplotlib 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3434) which has already been fixed (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/3453).

If you can edit your install you need to remove three characters.  You can also download a diff of the relevant code changes (https://github.com/jowr/matplotlib/commit/2191358c4d0dd2a705c418376a8a0e9e22c4ca9d.diff) which can be applied with patch.